# Is there any exponential function that can approximate $\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: special-functions, approximation

I need to approximate function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, using an exponential function like $g(x)$, using a parameter,$\sigma$ which when $\sigma$ goes to 0, g(x) becomes $g(x)$ equal to $f(x)$. Like $g(x) = exp(-x -\sigma)$, but it doesn't equal to $f(x)$ when $\sigma=0$. Is there any such function?

Edit: I want a function which doesn't have any term like $\frac{1}{x}$. Otherwise, I work with the original function. It is best to have summation of exponential.

Comment: maybe something like $$\frac1xe^{x\sigma}=e^{-\ln x}e^{x\sigma}=\exp\left(x\sigma-\ln x\right)$$

Comment: when you say exponential function $e^{f(x)}$ what do you expect $f$ to be ? linear, polynomial, rational ? Because evidently $\frac 1x=e^{-\ln(x)}$ so I guess you do not wnat $f$ logarithmic. Or maybe you want $\frac 1x=\sum a_i e^{b_i x}$ ?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @zwin. Yes. You are correct. I don't want any logarithmic or fractional function.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly, you want a function $g(x,\sigma)$, where $\sigma$ is a tuning parameter, than controls how close $g$ is to $\frac{1}{x}$; when $\sigma=0$, we want the difference to be zero.
Let
$$g(x,\sigma)=\frac{e^{\frac{\sigma}{x}}-1}{\sigma}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma^{k-1}}{k!x^k}$$
Than
$$\lim_{\sigma\to 0}g(x,\sigma)=\frac{1}{x}$$
as requested. I hope I understood your request correctly.

If you want your function to contain only exponential terms, we can define

$$g(x,\sigma)=\frac{e^{\frac{\sigma}{x}}-e^{x\sigma^2}}{\sigma}$$

To achieve the same limit.

#### Edit

After the clarifying edit to the original question, this answer is not viable.

Comment: I want a strawberries milkshake. Sorry no milk. Oh. Give me a chocolate milkshake then ! --> I dunno calculate $\frac 1x$, no problem it is approximable by $\frac{\sigma}x$. lol. ;-)